# Batch script issue assigning a variable value of mapped filename

Tags: batch-file

Im trying to write a Batch script that will log onto a bunch of xp computers (from a supplied list) and get the file modifed info for a particular file. (Same file and location on each Pc)

When the script runs it completes and logs onto each PC ok, but for some reason it passes a null value to `%filename%` and in the results file im getting an echo on message where the file modified info should be.

The problem seems to lie in the section of my code below (full script is at bottom):

```
set filename="G:\Documents and settings\user\desktop\samplefile.txt"
for %%C in (%filename%) DO (SET "bodytext=%bodytext%samplefile for %%A updated at %%~tC")
echo %bodytext% > results.txt
```

When I run just the above section of code by itself it works, so im assuming that when I map to the G drive and try to asssign the filename variable its not working.

Any ideas or help  is appreciated.

Thanks

Full Script

```
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=," %%A in (list_of_machines.txt) do (
net use G: \\%%A\c$ /User:domain\user password
echo processing IP_Address=%%A Hostname=%%B >> results.txt

set filename="G:\Documents and settings\user\desktop\samplefile.txt"
for %%C in (%filename%) DO (SET "bodytext=%bodytext%samplefile for %%A updated at %%~tC")
echo %bodytext% > results.txt
net use G: / delete
)
```

Comment: Batch can't handle nested parentheses `( )` see this article http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-brackets.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
set filename="G:\Documents and settings\user\desktop\samplefile.txt"
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=," %%A in (list_of_machines.txt) do (
net use G: \\%%A\c$ /User:domain\user password
echo processing IP_Address=%%A Hostname=%%B >> results.txt

for %%C in (%filename%) DO > results.txt echo %bodytext%samplefile for %%A updated at %%~tC
net use G: / delete
)
```

should work.

The main points:

Move the setting of `filename` outside of the `for` loop since the filename is constant. Within the `for` loop, `%filename%` (or any other `%var%`) is replaced by the value of `filename` (or the relevalt `var`) as it stood when the `for` was parsed.

You don't say what `bodytext` contains, so I'm assuming it's something set in your script before the posted code is executed.

Note the use of `>results.txt` before the text to be `echo`ed. This avoids a trailing space if the redirector has a leading space.

?? Are you sure about `>` ? If you want to accumulate the file, then you'd `>>` and if you want the file on the remote machine, then you'd need `g:results.txt`

Answer (score 0):

Open a command prompt window, execute `set /?` and read output help, especially the section about delayed environment variable expansion for usage in **for** loops and **if** blocks.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=," %%A in (list_of_machines.txt) do (
    net use G: \\%%A\c$ /User:domain\user password
    echo processing IP_Address=%%A Hostname=%%B>>results.txt

    set "filename=G:\Documents and settings\user\desktop\samplefile.txt"
    for %%C in ("!filename!") DO (SET "bodytext=!bodytext!samplefile for %%A updated at %%~tC")
    echo !bodytext!>>results.txt
    net use G: /delete
)
endlocal
```

Comment: Thanks Mofi, when I run it now, in my results file i get "sample.txt for x.x.x.x updated at sample.txt for x.x.x.x updated at sample.txt for x.x.x.x updated at " for each computer in list i supply, how come it writes it 3 times and also  it doesnt evaluate the %%~tC command, to give me the date modified info

Comment: Well, `bodytext` is not defined in your batch code and it can't be seen where this variable is cleared. `set "bodytext=!bodytext!` ... results in appending to previous string value of `bodytext` the new string. Therefore the value of `bodytext` becomes longer and longer with every loop run of outer loop. `%%~tC` is replaced by nothing if the file is not found. There is surely no `Documents and settings\user\desktop\samplefile.txt` on every connected drive C. You can whether use %USERPROFILE% nor %USERNAME% here in this code to access a file in desktop folder of unknown user on remote machine.

Answer (score 0):

```
wmic /node:"@%userprofile%\desktop\computername.txt" datafile where "name='C:\\windows\\win.ini'" get Lastmodified /format:csv
```

Where computername.txt is a file of computernames and/or ip addresses.

eg

```
computer1
127.0.0.1
computer2
```